# Unnest nested data recursively with technical ids (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I´m currently recieving JSON files from a source system. I process the json files and first store them as  nested delta tables. After that I flatten the nested data with pyspark. At the moment I pretty much wrote the flattening code by hand without any recursive logic. However since the number of live markets is increasing (>20 already) and the schemas differ for each market this is not acceptable anymore.

Therefore I would like to implement a scalable solution that takes the following things into account:- use pyspark- split arrays into seperate dataframes- automatically create technical ids that can be used to join the between the flattened tables (Not used at the moment but yields to some problems if not used)

This was inspired by the following package: https://github.com/kindly/flatterer
However the package can only be used with python and raw json files.

**Help needed**

- Are there any pypspark packages that can be used to flatten nested data and take into considerations the creation of technical ids?- If no package are available. Has anyone experience with flattening in pyspark and can share code?

**Example with current approach**

The following example shows how arrays should be split in seperate tables. It also shows some of the current problems when not using technical ids.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# lets create a nested schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("some_business_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("some_field", StringType(), True),
    StructField("businesspartners", ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("name", StringType(), True),
            StructField("profession", StringType(), True),
            StructField("addresses", ArrayType(
                StructType([
                    StructField("street", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("city", StringType(), True)
                ])
            ), True)
        ])
    ), True)
])

# 2 dummy entries for the schema
data = [
    ("1", "value1", [
        {"name": "claus", "profession": "data engineer", "addresses": [{"street": "Main St", "city": "Metropolis"}]},
        {"name": "joern", "profession": "data engineer", "addresses": [{"street": "Side St", "city": "Gotham"}]}
    ]),
    ("2", "value2", [
        {"name": "claus", "profession": "data scientist", "addresses": [{"street": "Sixt St", "city": "Manhatten"}]},
        {"name": "joern", "profession": "Football player", "addresses": [{"street": "Baker St", "city": "Fullham"}]}
    ]),

]

# the initial nested data to flatten
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
```

The schema includes 2 nested arrays. Therefore the flattening process should result in 3 tables:- main table- businesspartners table- businesspartner_addresses table

```
# create the top level table. 'some_business_id' is unique
main_table = df.select("some_business_id", "some_field")
```

​

```
businesspartner_table = (df
                         .withColumn("businesspartners", F.explode(F.col("businesspartners")))
                         .select(
                             "some_business_id", # added for joins
                             "businesspartners.name", 
                             "businesspartners.profession"
                             ))
```

​

"some_business_id" is added in order to allow joins between main and businesspartner table. However having a unique field is not always true. The businesspartner table itself does not have any unique column. This yields to problems when creating the businesspartner address table:

```
businesspartner_adress_table = (df
                         .withColumn("businesspartners", F.explode(F.col("businesspartners")))
                         .withColumn("addresses", F.explode(F.col("businesspartners.addresses")))
                         .select(
                             "some_business_id",
                             "businesspartners.name",
                             "businesspartners.profession",
                             "addresses.street",
                             "addresses.city",
                             )
                         )
```

I added name and profession which in combination may be unique. However uniqueness is not guaranteed. Therefore I think technical ids are required.

I order to add technical ids to the tables I experimented a bit with `monotonically_increasing_id` function. However I am still not sure what the best way to approach the problem is.